# Angular Flex Adding Padding to Each Div With Column

Tags: css, angular-flex-layout

I have a simple flex div set to a column like this:

```
<div fxFlex="column">
  <div>
    test
  </div>
  <div>
    test 2
  </div>
</div>
```

When the alignment is like this, there is top and bottom padding added to each div. When I set `fxFlex="row"` then it gets rid of the padding. I want each div to not have any padding in column direction.